# API gateway to my elastic beanstalk docker deployed app

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-api-gateway

My backend is a simple dockerized Node.js express app deployed onto elastic beanstalk. It is exposed on port 80. It would be located somewhere like

`mybackend.eba-p4e52d.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`

I can call my APIs on the backend

`mybackend.eba-p4e52d.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/hello`

`mybackend.eba-p4e52d.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/postSomeDataToMe`

and they work! Yay.

The URL is not very user friendly so I was hoping to set up API gateway to allow to me simply forward API requests from

`api.myapp.com/apiFamily/` to `mybackend.eba-p4e52d.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`

so I can call `api.myapp.com/apiFamily/hello` or `api.myapp.com/apiFamily/postMeSomeData`

Unfortunately, I can't figure out (i) if I can do this (ii) how to actually do it.

Can anybody point me to a resource that explains clearly how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. For this to happen you need two things:

- a **custom domain** that you own and control, e.g. myapp.com.
- a valid, public **SSL certificate** issued for that domain.

If you don't have them, and want to stay within AWS ecosystem, you can use **Route53** to buy and manage your custom domain. For SSL you can use **AWS ACM** which will provide you with free SSL certificate for the domain.

AWS instructions on how to set it up all is:

- [Setting up custom domain names for REST APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html)